# PHP file is suddenly 19 MB big in Chrome Console?

Tags: php, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have been experiencing long loading times on a web project I'm currently working on. It consits of a few small images, some HTML, CSS, JS and some texts that are loaded from a database. The whole page should be smaller than 2 MB.

To analyze the cause of the slow loading process I used the Chrome Console, which gave me a result, which I don't understand. It says, the PHP file is 17 MB big, although it is actually just 25 KB. Here's a screenshot of the Network results:

[image]

Where do these 17 MB come from? All the data in the database and every image on the server combined are not 17 MB big. What could have gone wrong here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the page, and maybe the PHP code that generates it

Comment: View source and check what there is? The size of the PHP file doesn’t reflect the size of the resulting data. At least there seems to be some inline JPEG etc

Comment: Thanks! I should have done that already. Looking at the source showed that there were thousands of lines of base64 image data, generated through the summernote text editor and mistakenly loaded in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 17 MB is the amount of data in the HTTP Response after the server has taken the HTTP request in and ran the PHP file.  You need to look at your PHP file to see whats creating all the data in the response.